# Kubernetes Cronjob Only Runs Half the Time

Tags: kubernetes

I want a job to trigger every 15 minutes but it is consistently triggering every 30 minutes.

**UPDATE:**

I've simplified the problem by just running:

```
kubectl run hello --schedule="*/1 * * * *" --restart=OnFailure --image=busybox -- /bin/sh -c "date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster"
```

As specified in the docs here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/

and yet the job still refuses to run on time.

```
$ kubectl get cronjobs
NAME               SCHEDULE      SUSPEND   ACTIVE    LAST SCHEDULE   AGE
hello              */1 * * * *   False     1         5m              30m
hello2             */1 * * * *   False     1         5m              12m
```

It took 25 minutes for the command line created cronjob to run and 7 minutes for the cronjob created from yaml.  They were both finally scheduled at the same time so it's almost like etcd finally woke up and did something?

**ORIGINAL ISSUE:**

When I drill into an active job I see `Status: Terminated: Completed` but 
`Age: 25 minutes` or something greater than 15.

In the logs I see that the python script meant to run has completed it's final print statement.  The script takes about ~2min to complete based on it's output file in s3.  Then no new job is scheduled for 28 more minutes.

I have tried with different configurations:

`Schedule: */15 * * * *` AND `Schedule: 0,15,30,45 * * * *`

As well as

`Concurrency Policy: Forbid` AND `Concurrency Policy: Replace`

What else could be going wrong here?

Full config with identifying lines modified:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  labels:
    type: f-c
  name: f-c-p
  namespace: extract
spec:
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          creationTimestamp: null
          labels:
            type: f-c
        spec:
          containers:
          - args:
            - /f_c.sh
            image: identifier.amazonaws.com/extract_transform:latest
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            env:
            - name: ENV
              value: prod
            - name: SLACK_TOKEN
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: slack_token
                  name: api-tokens
            - name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: aws_access_key_id
                  name: api-tokens
            - name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: aws_secret_access_key
                  name: api-tokens
            - name: F_ACCESS_TOKEN
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: f_access_token
                  name: api-tokens
            name: s-f-c
            resources: {}
            terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
            terminationMessagePolicy: File
          dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
          restartPolicy: Never
          schedulerName: default-scheduler
          securityContext: {}
          terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  schedule: '*/15 * * * *'
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  suspend: false
status: {}
```

Comment: the `*/15 * * * *` schedule should work fine, can you post your cronjob spec? Other fields might affect it (e.g. `startingDeadlineSeconds`)

Comment: Sure, added.  Thanks!

Comment: @Sosdoc want to take another look?  Even the simplest commands don't run on time

Comment: I would change  this : 

            `imagePullPolicy: Always`

to this :

           `imagePullPolicy:  IfNotPresent`

And look for the results. AFAIK its spending more time in pulling the image over the internet and hence getting into problems

Comment: @ProGirlXOXO I've tried both your job definition and the simple one from command line, both are scheduled correctly on my cluster (version 1.8.4). Could you tell your cluster version?

Comment: @Sosdoc Client GitVersion:"v1.9.2", Server GitVersion:"v1.8.7"

Comment: @samtoddler would this policy pull again if there is a new version to pull?

Comment: @samtoddler "The default pull policy is IfNotPresent which causes the Kubelet to skip pulling an image if it already exists."  So this is already the case in my test examples.

Comment: @ProGirlXOXO I checked changelogs but there's no mention of this issue, best suggestion I can offer is to attempt a restart of the docker process on the master (and maybe the api-server, try changing some configuration on the master to force a reload).

Comment: @ProGirlXOXO It will pull every time if we have this `imagePullPolicy: Always`. I had faced the similar case with [Chronos](https://github.com/mesos/chronos).

Comment: @ProGirlXOXO as per the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#updating-images) too. As its a cron so we don't have to pull the image every time over the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running these jobs in a test cluster I discovered that external circumstances prevented them from running as intended.

On the original cluster there were ~20k scheduled jobs.  The built-in scheduler for Kubernetes is not yet capable of handling this volume consistently.

The maximum number of jobs that can be reliably run (within a minute of the time intended) may depend on the size of your master nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that by design?

> A cron job creates a job object about once per execution time of its schedule. We say “about” because there are certain circumstances where two jobs might be created, or no job might be created. We attempt to make these rare, but do not completely prevent them. Therefore, jobs should be idempotent.

Ref. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#cron-job-limitations

Comment: "We attempt to make these rare."  This problem is not rare, it's consistent.